# Kotlin: How to use if statements in a lambda expression

Tags: android, kotlin

I did try this but i get to Error's.

```
fun main() {
    val addExclamationMark: (String) -> String = {if it.contains("!") -> it else -> it + "!"}
    println(addExclamationMark("Hallo Welt"))
}
```

Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but String was expected
Expecting a condition in parentheses '(...)'
Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

Can you please tell me how to do this right with some explanation so i understand Kotlin more ? ;)

Comment: Where did you get that using arrows for if flow control was a valid syntax? Is this some new experimental feature?

Answer (score 1):

Error `Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but String was expected` is because you defined the return datatype as String, but you didn't return anything. Two reasons for that:

- the -> in the condition are not necessary, they are too much
- the condition has to be in parentheses

Putting all together, this works:

```
fun main() {
    val addExclamationMark: (String) -> String = { if (it.contains("!")) it else it + "!"}
    println(addExclamationMark("Hallo Welt"))
}
```

[Check here](https://pl.kotl.in/t-TbyA2ZU)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a string, didn't return anything,

```
fun main() {
    Val addExclamationMark: (String) -> String = {
                if (it.contains("!")) {
                    it
                } else {
                    "$it!"
                }
            }

        println(addExclamationMark("Hallo Welt"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a lambda that take a `String` and returns a `String`
- In some situation, you can also use a method that implements a function by inference. The method have to respect the signature of the function.

```kotlin
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    // Lambda with String -> String
    val addExclamationMarkConst: (String) -> String = { if (it.contains("!")) it else "$it!" }
    println(addExclamationMarkConst("Hallo Welt"))
    
    // Method that implements the function with String -> Unit
    Optional.of("Hallo Welt").ifPresent(::printExclamationMark)
}

fun printExclamationMark(input: String): Unit {
    val elementToPrint: String = if (input.contains("!")) input else "$input!"
    println(elementToPrint)
}
```